# How to pipe the final result in bash file?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout

In the terminal both:

```
echo "hello" &&  read varname &&  echo $varname  | rev
```

and:

```
echo "hi" ; read varname ; echo $varname  | rev
```

give the expected result

If I write a script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hi" &&
read varname &&
echo $varname
```

```
./try.sh  | rev
```

The first line are sent to stdout :(
How to write a bash script to pipe the final result ?

edit:
I guess the problem I have is to understand how to pipe only what I want to pipe. All echo statement in the above example write to stdout.

edit2:
got this now:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo test >&0  &&
read varname &&
echo $varname
```

and it seems to work, is this a idiomatic way to solve the problem or is it some drawbacks to this solution. Google give nothing as usual.

Comment: If you are using && and/or ||, you will need the statements on the same line. Otherwise you can use if statements.

Comment: Not sure from your question but I'm guessing the issue is that `hi` printed as `ih`? Why not adding the `| rev` to the script?

Comment: I need to pipe different programs together, wrote this to demonstrate the problem I have using pipe to get the last stdout and not all of them

Comment: What is the final result? I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that hi printed as ih,  yes that is correct, sorry for not being clear

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you are confusing rev with tac. rev will reverse text line by line. tac will print the lines from files starting from the bottom to the top. Maybe ./try.sh | tac?

Comment: @somina [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84656) there os explanation for `>&0`, what you doing is redirecting `stdout` to `stdin`.

Comment: @Shmuel, yes I wrote that in the comment to Chai, It just feels a bit awkward to send this back and then just do nothing with the value. I should like to kill the damn thing

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply the pipe only to specific lines of the shell script from the outside. What you can do, however, is to print the first "hi" to stderr, in which case your example would only reverse the final text:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "hi" >&2 &&
read varname &&
echo $varname
```

```sh
./try.sh  | rev
```

Comment: this is the same answer Chai provided, both answers have the same timestamp so I don't know who answer first, thanks anyway

Comment: @somina the put +1 for both at least.

Answer (score 1):

What if you sent the first line to stderr instead?
Would this work for you? That first line echoes hi to stderr.

#!/bin/bash

```
>&2 echo "hi" &&
read varname &&
echo $varname
```

The output looks like if I type in hello as the input to the script

```
hi
hello
olleh
```

Comment: this is better! , but I should like to use stderr for errors, this is a step in the right direction, maybe it should be possible to redirect stdout to stdin ?

Comment: just tried to use echo test >&0 and it seems to work : )